# WinAPI - Problem to append text to an editbox

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, message

I created a simple window with a multiline Edit Control:

```
Edit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("EDIT"), NULL,
                    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE,
                    20, 200, 200, 200,
                    hWnd, (HMENU)EDIT, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
```

If I set text using a WM_SETTEXT message, I don't get errorrs, but if I use EM_REPLACESEL
I get Error 5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED):

```
SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hWnd, EDIT), EM_REPLACESEL, 0, (LPARAM)TEXT("\r\nSome text"));
if (GetLastError()) {
    /* Error 5 ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED */
}
```

Same problem with EM_SETSEL:

```
SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hWnd, EDIT), EM_SETSEL, (WPARAM)(0),(LPARAM)(-1));
SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hWnd, EDIT), EM_REPLACESEL, 0, (LPARAM)TEXT("\r\nSome text"));
if (GetLastError()) {
    /* Error 5 ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED */
}
```

I noticed that if I send a WM_SETFOCUS message before the EM_REPLACESEL there are no error:

```
SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hWnd, EDIT), WM_SETFOCUS, (WPARAM)GetDlgItem(hWnd, EDIT), 0);
SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hWnd, EDIT), EM_REPLACESEL, 0, (LPARAM)TEXT("\r\nSome text"));
if (GetLastError()) {
    /* NO ERRORS */
}
```

How can I resolve this problem?
Do I have to send a WM_SETFOCUS message before the EM_REPLACESEL one every time I want to append some text to my Editbox?

Thanks for help!

Comment: What if you just `SetLastError(0)` before sending the `EM_REPLACESEL` message?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a `EM_SETSEL` first and then do your `EM_REPLACESEL`.

Example:

```
SendMessage(hwnd, EM_SETSEL, WPARAM(0), LPARAM(-1) );
SendMessage(hwnd, EM_REPLACESEL, WPARAM(TRUE), LPARAM(str) );
```

Comment: @Mario, if you get error 5 (access denied), it means that you don't have the proper rights.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely getting access denied because of UIPI.

Is the Edit box created by the same application that's attempting to send messages? If not, the application doing the SendMessage probably has a lower UIPI level than the application that owns the Edit.

If you do, in fact, own both the application that created the Edit control and the application sending the messages, you can allow specific messages in by using [ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd388202.aspx).

```
ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx(hwndOfWindowReceivingMessage, EM_REPLACESEL, 
    MSGFLT_ALLOW, NULL);
```

Comment: Yes the Edit box is created by the same application.

I also tryed your code before the EM_REPLACESEL:

ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx(GetDlgItem(hWnd, EDIT), EM_REPLACESEL, MSGFLT_ALLOW, NULL);

but I get the same error.

Comment: Could you check if the ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx succeeded? If not, what is the error code?

Comment: ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx succeeded,
but, since the Edit control is created by the same application do I have to call ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx in any case?

Comment: You shouldn't. But as far as I know, only UIPI issues can give you access denied errors on SendMessage. But if everything is contained in the same application, it shouldn't be an issue. I'm not sure what the problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately GetLastError is not documented as supported for EM_REPLACESEL meaning you will have to devise some alternate strategy for catching failures.  Maybe some text length calculations would work.

Having said that, I was curious about why the access denied error was being returned.  I set a data break point on the address where SetLastError/GetLastError store the error code and found that it was deep within GDI, not directly from the edit control.  Not very helpful but at least an interesting tidbit.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use SendDlgItemMessage instead of SendMessage.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that EM_SETSEL, EM_REPLACESEL, etc. act on the caret; if the focus is not on the control, it has no caret, and these messages won't work. Either your user has to click on the control to make it gain the focus, or you have to do WM_SETFOCUS first. Unfortunately that's how the control works, it has no memory of the selection after it loses focus (and neither can have one before it gains it).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
wchar_t buffer[256] = _T("here I am at camp granada \r\n");
int ndx = GetWindowTextLength (hEdit);
SetFocus (hEdit);
SendMessage(hEdit, EM_SETSEL, (WPARAM)ndx, (LPARAM)ndx);
SendMessage(hEdit, EM_REPLACESEL, WPARAM(TRUE), (LPARAM)buffer );
```